# Angular iframe after fully loaded spining loader not working in chrome incognito

Tags: javascript, angular

Loading a spinner using this component

```
    <ucmloader [objLoaderStatus]="objLoaderStatus">
    </ucmloader>
```

After fully loaded iframe, loader status are going to false

```
  <iframe #myframe class="csocial__iframe" (load)="objLoaderStatus=false;" [src]="iframeUrl"></iframe>
```

This coding is working good for all browser, but in chrome incognito mode loader is not spinning while iframe loaded, shows only blank page before loading.